# Qual a melhor forma de gerar arquivos pdf via webservice?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, pdf

Tenho um webservice Soap e me deparei com a necessidade gerar documentos pdf.
 
Alguém já trabalhou com geração de muitos documentos via webservice e quais tecnologias utilizaram? Quais tecnologias obtiveram melhor desempenho, facilidade de trabalho etc(quais foram:utilização de determinado Framework, criação de rotinas agendadas no server, chamadas de métodos assíncronos etc)?

Comment: Você possui muitas perguntas em uma só. Seria melhor você segmentar suas perguntas em outras, pois da forma que está ficaria difícil responder todas.

Answer (score 3):

Estou em um trabalho disso neste momento. E, o mais simples, para gerar **PDF** a partir de um HTML e funcionou muito bem comigo, é o [NReco.PdfGenerator](http://www.nrecosite.com/pdf_generator_net.aspx).

Gratuito, rápido, e fácil demais de usar.

```
var htmlContent = String.Format("<body>Hello world: {0}</body>", 
        DateTime.Now);
var htmlToPdf = new NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter();
var pdfBytes = htmlToPdf.GeneratePdf(htmlContent);
```

Ou mesmo direto de uma URL:

```
htmlToPdf.GeneratePdfFromFile("http://www.nrecosite.com/", null, "export.pdf");
```